# PS3 connects to Wi-Fi but fails to sign into PSN?

Tags: ps3, psn

I have two modems. One that is an ADSL and the other one is a Wi-Fi.

My PS3 works fine when I directly connect the ethernet cable from the ADSL modem to it, but whenever I try to connect through my Wi-Fi, it keeps failing at the PSN sign in.

This is my Wi-Fi router - http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/cat-9_TL-WR740N.html#specifications

I already tried disabling Media Servers. Am I supposed to be modifying any settings, such as MTU or uPNP? Or is there an issue with my Wi-Fi modem?

Comment: Why do you have two routers?  Are you forwarding from the Wifi router to the ADSL one properly?

Comment: Yes. The internet connection works fine. I am even able to open the Internet Browser in PS3, when connected to Wi-Fi. It just won't sign in.

Comment: Sounds like the correct port isn't forwarded properly.

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: the psn ports are

TCP-Ports: 80, 443, 5223 
UDP-Ports: 3478, 3479, 3658

Comment: Can you try connecting manually to psn? (by clicking the connect to button). if so, what error message do you get?